# Ubuntu: "X" mark on the top-right corner of respective file icons

Tags: icons, c

I am new to ubuntu/ linux. Hence, please accept my apology for asking very trivial questions. Also, I googled; but, did not find suitable answer.

I installed a third party lib: [Taucs](http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/)  (location on my computer: /usr/local/lib/taucs_full).

1) Most of files, have "X" mark on the top-right corner of respective icons. What does that mean?

2) Also, I can not use the following include statement from my C-code

```
#include "/usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/taucs.h"
```

I get the following error:

```
 fatal error: /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/taucs.h: Permission denied
 #include "/usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/taucs.h"
```

How should I grant access to this location?

UPDATE (added the output of two commands as asked by @muru):
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/
total 768

```
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar    963 Aug 31  2003 blas_aux.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar   3170 Aug 28  2003 taucs_ccs_base.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  23708 Aug 28  2003 taucs_ccs_factor_llt.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  28238 Aug 28  2003 taucs_ccs_generators.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  26502 Sep  4  2003 taucs_ccs_io.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  90790 Aug 28  2003 taucs_ccs_ooc_llt.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar 103873 Aug 28  2003 taucs_ccs_ooc_lu.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  12280 Jun 19  2003 taucs_ccs_ops.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  21043 Aug 29  2003 taucs_ccs_order.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  11328 Aug 31  2003 taucs_ccs_solve_llt.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  12489 Aug 28  2003 taucs_ccs_xxt.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar   5200 Aug 31  2003 taucs_complex.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  37588 Aug 28  2003 taucs_gremban.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  25721 Sep  4  2003 taucs.h
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  10666 Aug 28  2003 taucs_iter.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  19295 Sep  4  2003 taucs_linsolve.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar   1947 Aug 24  2003 taucs_logging.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar   6912 Feb 23  2003 taucs_malloc.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar   9061 Sep  1  2003 taucs_memory.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  40571 Aug 28  2003 taucs_ooc_io.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  14946 Sep  4  2003 taucs_private.h
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  10344 Aug 28  2003 taucs_recvaidya.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  99089 Sep  4  2003 taucs_sn_llt.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar   5478 Feb 23  2003 taucs_superlu.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar   9808 Sep  1  2003 taucs_timer.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar  90981 Aug 28  2003 taucs_vaidya.c
-rw------- 1 31967 dkumar   5174 Aug 31  2003 taucs_vec_base.c
```

dkumar@dkumar-Precision-WorkStation-T7500 /usr/local/lib/taucs_full $ namei -m /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/

```
   f: /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/
     drwxr-xr-x /
     drwxr-xr-x usr
     drwxr-xr-x local
     drwxr-xr-x lib
     drwxr-xr-x taucs_full
     drwxr-xr-x src
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `ls -l /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/` and `namei -m /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/`.

Comment: @muru updated with output of these commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it looks like all you need to do is grant read permissions to the files, since right now only user `dkumar` has read permission. If you have `sudo` permissions, you can do:

```
sudo chmod +r /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/src/*
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, would you please let me know what is the meaning of "X" mark on the top-right corner of respective file icons?

Comment: @GarimaSingh I'm not sure, but I think it means that you don't have read permission for those files.